# How can i connect PHP 5.5.x or above version to mssql 2008 R2 in wamp?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i connect PHP 5.5.x  or above version to mssql 2008 R2 in wamp?
Versions :
php : 5.5
Compiler : MSVC11
Architecture : x86
Tread safety : enabled

I tried with following step :
1. Tried connecting with  sqlsrv_connect()
Example code below(test-connect.php) :

```
    <?php
$serverName = "192.168.1.5";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"testDB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"sa123");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

When I run file test-connect.php, its throwing the following error :

```
**"Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()"**
```

2. I tried putting following two DLL file to PHP ext folder 
   a) php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
   b) php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
3. And updated php.ini with the following extensions
   extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
4. Restarted all services

Still it throw below given error :-

```
**Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )**
```

Can anyone help me with fixing this? Is this the problem with versions of Apache/PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Look here : 
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Basicly you need to install library which url is in your error desc and put to php.ini this library, somethin like this:

```
Extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```